# Calculate Sum with cells that contain a string that stands for a specific value

Tags: excel, function, sum, formula, key-value

I want to solve the following.

In Cell A1 i type "S". In Cell B1 i type "U". 
Now I want to define a key value table somewhere on the excelsheet -> (S=8;U=3)
If I create a sum function for cell A to B the result should be 11.

Comment: You can use two vlookups. Syntax: `VLOOKUP(lookup_value, lookup_table, column_to_return, 0) [0 is for exact match].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a table with letters in `Y2:Y10` and then corresponding amounts in `Z2:Z10` then you can use this formula to get 11

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(Y2:Y10,A1:B1,Z2:Z10))`